# Stubbing a mock object does not work

Tags: spock

I have a factory class carfactory that i create a mock object of.

```
def mockCar = Mock(Car)
def mockFactory = Mock(CarFactory)
this.mockCar.getDoors(_)   >> ["a","b"]
this.mockFactory.getCar(_) >> this.mockCar
```

Now when the test runs i get a mockCar object from the factory but not the set from the getDoors(_) call.
I get a empty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of `this.` is incorrect because `mockCar` and `mockFactory` are local variables, not instance fields. After fixing this, the shown code works fine (I just double-checked in [Spock Web Console](http://meetspock.appspot.com/script/77001)). If you get back an empty set, chances are that your real code has another problem not shown here.

Comment: The problem occurs when in the actual code like this, when i call carfactory,getcar i get back a mockCar . However when in the next line i call mockCar.getDoors i no longer get a set .

Comment: You'd have to provide a minimal reproducible example. As can be seen in my Spock Web Console link above, the code you showed in your initial post works just fine (after fixing the `this.`). Also make sure to use the latest Spock version (0.7), although I doubt it will make a difference.